# joomla 2.5 native modal box next and prev buttons

Tags: joomla, mootools, modal-dialog

I'm using joomla 2.5, and need to add next and prev buttons to the joomla native modal behaviour (media/system/js/modal.js).

I have multiple thumbnails which each opens a modal box with a youtube player.
I'de like the ability to move to the next movie/prev videos with arrow buttons which will be inside the modal box.

Any chance anyone ever did this or should I just let it go and use a plugin?
Thanks...
Yanipan

Comment: Next/previous to what?  Another article?

Comment: You are right, I'm adding the missing details. Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I simply used JCEMediaBox, it keeps the same syntax, you need to change the .modal class to another one (as defined) and should work ok...